# SQL Function returning sum value of all rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, t-sql, udf

I have two tables, Job table and Item table. I have created a function where I'm trying to return a sum value of customer price for each individual job. Instead it returns a total sum of all jobs combined. The following is my function that I have created:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ApprvStatTotal(@JobNumber nvarchar(255)) 
RETURNS int  
AS  
BEGIN    
    DECLARE @ int    

    SELECT @ = Sum(CustmPrice)
    FROM dbo.Job 
    INNER JOIN dbo.Item ON dbo.Job.JobNumber = dbo.Item.JobNumber
    WHERE dbo.Job.JobNumber = dbo.Item.JobNumber 
      AND CustmApprvStat = 'Closed' 
       OR CustmApprvStat = 'Approved'

    RETURN @
End
```

I would like to get a total sum of of customer price of each individual job instead of overall total of all jobs, if that makes sense. If someone could help me with this, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  Your first `WHERE` condition is redundant with the `ON` clause.

Comment: That OR is processed last and you are not even using @JobNumber

Answer (score 3):

Your `WHERE` clause is malformed.  Conditions between tables should go in the `ON` clause.  Also, you can use `IN` instead of `OR`:

```
SELECT @ = Sum(CustmPrice)
FROM dbo.Job j INNER JOIN
     dbo.Item i
     ON j.JobNumber = i.JobNumber
WHERE CustmApprvStat IN ('Closed', 'Approved');
```

Your `WHERE` clause is being parsed as:

```
WHERE (dbo.Job.JobNumber = dbo.Item.JobNumber AND CustmApprvStat = 'Closed') OR 
      CustmApprvStat = 'Approved'
```

Hmmm, because the first condition is redundant with the `ON` clause, that might not be your problem.

If you want it broken out by jobs, use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT j.JobNumber, Sum(CustmPrice)
FROM dbo.Job j INNER JOIN
     dbo.Item i
     ON j.JobNumber = i.JobNumber
WHERE CustmApprvStat IN ('Closed', 'Approved')
GROUP BY j.JObNumber;
```

EDIT:

This might be what you are trying to do:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ApprvStatTotal(@JobNumber nvarchar(255)) 
RETURNS int  
AS  
BEGIN    
    DECLARE @retval int ;   

    SELECT @retval = Sum(CustmPrice)
    FROM dbo.Job j INNER JOIN
         dbo.Item i
         ON j.JobNumber = i.JobNumber
    WHERE j.JobNumber = @JobNumber AND
          CustmApprvStat IN ('Closed', 'Approved');

    RETURN @retval
End;
```

Comment: Gordon, I created a query based off the Group By:

Comment: My query is :Select JobID, sum(CustmPrice) as "ApprvStatTotal"
From Item
WHERE CustmApprvStat IN ('Closed', 'Approved')
Group By JobID  This worked. Is there a way to create a function with the above query in a computed field ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check below SQL function

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ApprvStatTotal(@JobNumber nvarchar(255)) 
RETURNS int  
AS  
BEGIN    
    DECLARE @sum int    

    SELECT @sum = Sum(CustmPrice)
    FROM dbo.Job 
    INNER JOIN dbo.Item ON dbo.Job.JobNumber = dbo.Item.JobNumber
    WHERE dbo.Job.JobNumber = @JobNumber 
      AND (CustmApprvStat = 'Closed' OR CustmApprvStat = 'Approved')

    RETURN @sum
End
```

You did not use the input parameter @JobNumber in your original SQL function code. So I just added in the WHERE clause

Comment: Eralper- I just wanted to say thank you. Your query worked great. Once again, thank you.